# NSWindow autosave - position not saved on 2nd monitor

Tags: objective-c, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, autosave

In Yosemite (and possibly earlier), the window frame autosave mechanism does not honour the automatic positioning of windows that have been moved from the main display to a second monitor, or any position that overlaps a second monitor.

Instead, when next instantiated, the window is automatically positioned at the previous location (if there was a valid position recorded in defaults) or the default position for the window, or in the case of overlapping windows, a position that puts the window entirely on the main screen.

This occurs regardless of whether the autosave name property is set on the window in Interface Builder, or through an NSWindowController. e.g.

```
-(void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];
    [self setShouldCascadeWindows:NO];
    [self setWindowFrameAutosaveName:@"MyWindowAutoSaveName"];
}
```

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 3):

I could never get the autosave to restore to the 2nd monitor. No amount of flogging would make it work. It would restore to the first monitor at the same xy position as the window was on the 2nd monitor. To solve the problem I gave up using the autosave API and made my own.

When the window's windowWillClose: method is called first store a BOOL that indicates if the window was full screen zoomed. Next if the window was not zoomed (more on this in a second) use NSStringFromRect and save the window's frame rect.

```
-(void)windowWillClose:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSString  *mainWindowFrameString;

  [_defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[_flimFlamViewController windowIsFullScreen]] forKey:QUITTING_ZOOM_STATE];

  if ([_flimFlamViewController windowIsFullScreen] == NO) {
    mainWindowFrameString = NSStringFromRect([_ourWindow frame]);
    [_defaults setObject:mainWindowFrameString forKey:MAIN_WINDOW_FRAME];
    }

  [_defaults synchronize];

}
```

Conversely when the window is created (possibly in awakeFromNib:) load the string from NSUserDefaults and use NSRectFromString to get the bounds. Check the frames dimensions for zero to see if this is the first time the app has been started. If the frame is not all zeros set the window's frame to that CGRect.

```
  mainWindowFrameString = [_defaults objectForKey:MAIN_WINDOW_FRAME];       // get the last saved window frame values
  mainWindowFrame = NSRectFromString(mainWindowFrameString);                // convert it to a CGRect

  if ((mainWindowFrame.size.width != 0) && (mainWindowFrame.size.height != 0)) {
    [_ourWindow setFrame:mainWindowFrame display:YES];
    }
  else {
    [_ourWindow center];
    }
```

To handle case of a window being fullscreen zoomed when the window was closed, first save the frame's position before it goes full screen - you will use this later when the window opens back up to put the window on the proper monitor.

```
-(void)windowWillEnterFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
  NSString  *mainWindowFrameString;

  // save the frame's coordinates before going full screen

  mainWindowFrameString = NSStringFromRect([_ourWindow frame]);
  [_defaults setObject:mainWindowFrameString forKey:MAIN_WINDOW_FRAME];
}
```

Then in viewWillAppear: determine if you need to zoom the window (the window at this point has already been put on the proper monitor). toggleFullScreen: will cause the window to go full screen.

```
  lastZoomStateDefault = [_defaults objectForKey:QUITTING_ZOOM_STATE];
  _windowIsFullScreen = [lastZoomStateDefault boolValue];

  if (_windowIsFullScreen == YES) {
    [_window toggleFullScreen:nil];
    }
```